# Throw custom exception from a normal try/catch

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have this example code:

```cs
static void Main (string[] args) {
    
    try {
        int number = 8;
        int divisor = 0;
        int result = number / divisor;

        Console.WriteLine ($"Result of: {number} / {divisor} is: {result}");        
    } catch (DivideByZeroException) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Can't divide by 0");
        throw new MyFormattedException ("Format exception from DivideByZeroException");
    } catch (MyFormattedException e) {
        Console.WriteLine ();
        Console.WriteLine (@"/=========== EXCEPCION ==========\");
        Console.WriteLine ($"| {e.Message}");
        Console.WriteLine (@"\=========== EXCEPCION ==========/");
    }

    Console.ReadLine ();
}
```

I expect in console:

```
Can't divide by 0
/=========== EXCEPCION ==========\
| Format exception from DivideByZeroException
\=========== EXCEPCION ==========/
```

but nevertheless I have a Run-time exception without catching.

Do I need to have another try/catch inside the `DivideByZeroException` catch??

Dotnetfiddle demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8wtHp4

**UPDATE:**

First, thanks for the comments. The previous code is only for explains purposes and I know I can put the code from the last catch in the `DivideByZeroException` catch.

In my real project, I´m using [Pkcs11Interop](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop) to interact with a smarcard. I created a custom class `SmartCard` for encapsulate operations and validations against the Smartcard and the `SmartCardException` with an enum `SmartcardErrorType` with all my possible errors.

In general terms, this is my actual code.
I wanted to be able to use this structure without putting the `using session` inside another try / catch of `Pkcs11Exception`.

```cs
private async Task SaveCertificateAsync () {
    try {

        // A general class to show a progress bar, and messages to the user
        StatusPanel.BeginProgress ();
        StatusPanel.Message = "Init smartcard reader...";

        // This is my custom class to make init validations before to write to the card.
        // This init method can throw different exceptions from SmartcardErrorType enum:
        //     SMARTCARD_TOKEN_OWNER_UNKNOWN
        //     KEYSTORE_USER_HAS_MULTIPLE_CERTS
        //     etc...
        Smartcard smartcard = await Smartcard.InitSmartCard ("XXXXXXXX");

        StatusPanel.Message = "Validating card...";
        // This method can throw different exceptions from SmartcardErrorType enum too
        bool validCard = smartcard.IsValidCard ();

        while (!validCard) {
            MessageDialogResult dialogResult = await CardDialogManager.ShowChangeCard (this, DialogCoordinatorInstance);

            if (dialogResult == MessageDialogResult.Negative)
                throw new SmartCardException (SmartcardErrorType.SMARTCARD_OVERALL_PROCESS_CANCELED);

            // more code...
        }

        StatusPanel.Message = "Request PIN Card...";
        string pin = await CardDialogManager.RequestNormalPin (this, DialogCoordinatorInstance, smartcard.GetPinCounter ());

        using (ISession session = smartcard.GetSession (SessionType.ReadWrite)) {

            // Now with the pin from the user, I´m trying to login and this can produce Pkcs11Exception exceptions                
            session.Login (CKU.CKU_USER, pin);

            // more code...

        }
    } catch (Pkcs11Exception e) {
        // I just want to control some concrete of the many that there are
        if (e.RV == CKR.CKR_PIN_INCORRECT)
            throw new SmartCardException (SmartcardErrorType.SMARTCARD_USER_PIN_INCORRECT);

        if (e.RV == CKR.CKR_TOKEN_NOT_PRESENT)
            throw new SmartCardException (SmartcardErrorType.SMARTCARD_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND);

        throw new SmartCardException ("Other exceptions no controlled... ");
    } catch (SmartCardException se) {
        StatusPanel.EndErrorProgress (se.Message);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Exact same as the linked question. Now, I know that I need nested try/catch.

Thank you.

Comment: The `catch (MyFormattedException e)` only applies to the `try`, not to exceptions thrown from any prior `catch` blocks. I don't know what you need to solve your problem: your demo could be solved by removing `MyFormattedException` entirely and just putting the logic into the `catch (DivideByZeroException)`

Comment: As @canton7 said you need this only `catch (DivideByZeroException e) {
   Console.WriteLine ("Can't divide by 0");
   Console.WriteLine ();
   Console.WriteLine (@"/=========== EXCEPCION ==========\");
   Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
   Console.WriteLine (@"\=========== EXCEPCION ==========/");
  }`

Comment: Yes, I know what you saying, this is only a demo. In my real WPF app, I´m writing in a smarcard using [Pkcs11Interop](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop) wich has his low level custom exceptions and I´m using my high level custom exception to make validations, update UI, close clean objects, etc... and I just wish I didn't have to repeat the same code on every catch block.

Comment: @Randolf Again I can't give specific advice without seeing a more representative example. But you could use `try { try { ... } catch (...) { throw MyException(); } } catch (MyException) { ... }`, or you could use a helper method / local function

Comment: I updated the question. Thank you @canton7 and Rao-Hammas.